# Adding SPF records when using both Google Workspace and SendGrid

Tags: gmail, spf

I previously didn't have any SPF set up on my domain. I use Google Workspace. I now use the SendGrid API.

This is what I set as the SPF record

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:_mailcust.gandi.net include:sendgrid.net ~all
```

SendGrid verified.

However on an email that was sent using Gmail I received a bounce back (email addresses redacted for security)

```
550 5.7.23 : Sender address rejected: Message rejected due to: SPF fail - not authorized. Please see http://spf.libraesva.com/Why?s=mfrom;id=xxxx@xxxx.com;ip=209.85.218.45;r=xxxx@xxxx.com
```

And on that link it states...

```
...they need to change xxxx.com SPF record so that it authorizes mail-ej1-f45.google.com (209.85.218.45). They should add this to their SPF record:
a:mail-ej1-f45.google.com
```

But I am curious to know why I need to use `a:mail-ej1-f45.google.com` instead of or as well as `include:_spf.google.com`

I contacted Google support about this and they stated:

> If you're using sendgrid and Gmail and please add the below SPF
> records "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include include:sendgrid.net
> ~all"

But this is what I had already set as the SPF record and they haven't been much help since contacting them.

Currently my SPF looks like the following below but I'd like to know:

1. Why I have to add `a:mail-ej1-f45.google.com` to the SPF record
2. Can I have both `include:_spf.google.com` and `a:mail-ej1-f45.google.com` in the record?

   "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:_mailcust.gandi.net include:sendgrid.net a:mail-ej1-f45.google.com ~all"

Comment: Can you give us the actual domain in question? Your SPF record looks fine *on paper*, so I'm wondering if it's actually correctly in place. Ignore the generalized advice on that page; `mail-ej1-f45.google.com` is `209.85.218.45` which is included by `_netblocks.google.com` which is in turn included by `_spf.google.com`.